# Choosing between an INSTEAD OF/AFTER trigger and a UDF

Tags: sql-server, triggers, user-defined-functions

I have a business rule in my database that says an ID must match a list of specific ID's in order to be valid. I can't use a CHECK constraint in this instance as it requires a subquery to find the valid ID's, hence I need to use a trigger.

Put simply, in order for a record to be inserted into table A. The ID field (numeric) in table A must be present in tables B or C.

I could however use a scalar UDF to check if the ID is valid, but this seems a bit like function abuse. I've done this a few times in my database already and although it works, it just looks 'wrong'.

Back to the triggers, I can't decide which trigger I would need to use in this case as they seem to both work, except the error is caught at different stages.

Using an INSTEAD OF trigger will catch the invalid ID before it is inserted/updated, but the code for this trigger seems a little bit over complicated. (Takes 12 variables and a long unwieldy INSERT statement)

An AFTER trigger will perform the same task, but the error is caught after the row is inserted and then the operation is rolled back.

Now despite all three of these approaches working, one of these must be more 'appropriate' for the task?

Comment: Triggers commonly used for update/delete/insert operations, and you want to check valid id before insert. use UDF or subquery to check,e.g: if @id  in (select myid from mytable)
begin
--do your business logic
end

Comment: That's something I've done before in the database, just wasn't sure if it was the generally accepted way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use User Defined Function and encapsulate your validation codes in it. It should look something like this.

```
--  Create Dummy Table
CREATE TABLE Employee 
( ID INT, Name VARCHAR(50), Age TINYINT)
GO

--  Function to verify age of employee
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.verifyAge   
( @Age TINYINT)  
RETURNS BIT  
    BEGIN   
        IF (@Age IS NULL OR @Age >= 18)
            RETURN 1

        RETURN 0; 
    END;

--  Add check constraint
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee
    ADD CONSTRAINT Chk_verifyAge CHECK (dbo.verifyAge(Age) = 1)
GO
--  Test check Constraint
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee
        ( ID, Name, Age )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Dummy',17)
GO
```

[image]